# Change and Add Webdevelopment Code in SSRS

Tags: html, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reportserver

Goal:
If the user use IE, I want a part of the sourcecode, that is "`<div id="ctl31_ctl09" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; ;">"`
 to be changed into
 `"<div id="ctl31_ctl09" style="width: 150%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; ;">"` in SSRS.
Firefox still gonna use the orginal sourcecode if the user(s) use FF.

Problem:
How and where should I enable to change the source code after the original code is generated.

My logical solution and ide would be:
1. Generate the original code and display the result based on the original code in
     `http://myserver/report`.
2. if the browser use IE, change part of the sourcecode that is:
   `"<div id="ctl31_ctl09" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; ;">"`
 into
 `"<div id="ctl31_ctl09" style="width: 150%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; ;">"`.

The question is

> how to do it?

I strongly believe that you also gonna need to use and change part of the code in ReportingServices.js

Information:
*I'm using SQL server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2008 Professional.
*The sourcecode is webdevelopment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to download IE11 and this problem will disappear.